# Resolving IP address from google services

Tags: internet, ip

I was using my work computer today, and connect to various internet services (e.g. google, gmail, etc.) Is there a way to check the IP of my work computer from home by looking at these internet services?

Comment: you can also go to http://whatismyip.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if you login to Gmail look at the bottom of the page for:

```
Last account activity: x hours ago on y. Details
```

Just click on `Details` and you should be able to pin down your work IP address.

Answer (score 2):

On GMail, at the very bottom of the window, it will show what IP you're connected with. For general use, you can go to a site like [IPAddress.com](http://ipaddress.com) to see what your outside address is

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Gmail account and on the bottom of your inbox there is a Details link. Click it and it will display the last 10 IP's that have accessed your account.